# UIList setting an icon in a prop gives unexpected result

Tags: python

I found an oddity in the UIList when i try to show the hide state of a set of objects. Here is a class definition that works perfect:

class MeshesPropVarList(bpy.types.UIList):

```
def draw_item(self,
              context,
              layout,
              data,
              item,
              icon,
              active_data,
              active_propname
              ):
    ob=context.scene.objects[item.name]
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    row=col.row(align=True)
    row.prop(ob,"hide", text='', emboss=False) # <== icon as expected"
    row.prop(ob,"select", text=item.name)
```

But as soon as i try to set the icon to anything else, then i get wrong icons when the object is not visible. When i change the last 2 lines in the class as follows:

```
    row.prop(ob,"hide", text='', icon='BLANK1', emboss=False)
    row.prop(ob,"select", text=item.name)
```

Then i see the blank icon only when the object is visible. Otherwise i get the light bulb icon. What is going on here ?

[image]

Comment: At a first glance, I think you need a fallback in case there the property is `False` (There is a reason why `'RESTRICT_VIEW_ON'` is right next to `'RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF'` in the icon list). Did you already tried assigning something like `icon='MESH_UVSPHERE' if not ob.hide else 'META_EMPTY'`?

Comment: yes, of course i did that first. That was when i found the glitch. Using 'BLANK1' in the example above is just a demonstration that the list behaves utterly wrong or at least in a totally unexpected way.

Comment: `'LAMP'` is right next to `BLANK1` in the list... https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAjMv.jpg